# How are the parts of a XOR are called?

Tags: xor

How are the parts of a XOR are called?

```
A xor B = C
```

What is A and B called
For Division it is:

```
A / B = C
```

A = divisor,  B = dividend, C = quotient

For sums (and XOR is symmetric as the sum is) it is

```
A + B = C
```

summand for A and B, and sum for C

But I am missing a term for xor, how is it called and is there even one?

Sure you could go with operand or parameter or input or [...], but that is very generic, I would like to have a non-generic version.

Comment: I am not looking to program it. I just wanted to discuss it with a friend and we stumbled on the fact that neither of us knows the term.

Comment: How about “operands”? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand

Comment: That is a way to go, but it seems very generic, doesn't it? And how would you then describe A xor B and C?

Comment: One operand is XORed with another operand and the result is ANDed with a third operand? There just don't exist specific names for operands in boolean evaluations.

Comment: Can you give another example of a named boolean / logical operand? Probably it exists only for arithmetic operations.

Comment: Good idea, sadly I can not. It might be a general boolean "operand" problem. But that shouldn't stop us form if there isn't one, defining one. I stumbled on it as a discussion of algorithms became quite hard without a term. So if it is useful, it should exist even when rarely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As a friend of mine suggested)

You could call it XORant so the full version would be

```
Xorant1 ExclusiveOred Xorant2 ResultsIn TheXORed
```

But I have no Idea if this is commonly used.

Comment: Although I agree that introducing this could be useful if you are dealing with xor a lot, I would argue that this worsens the problem. In everyday conversation, operand or input will be much clearer. Consider these sentences: "To solve this, we take the XOR of the inputs" and "To solve this and calculate TheXORed, we ExclusiveOr the XORants". Nobody will ever not go "Heh?" on the second sentence.

Comment: I completely agree with you @Dustin, it is certainly confusing in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 5):

As Soonts mentioned, the general name for `thing operation thing` would be an operand.

XOR being a logical or boolean operation, you could call it a logical / boolean operand. Often, they are also called input. Depending on usage, set or statement also works.

Comment: How would you describe A xor B and C then? Is there a non-generic version?

Comment: Same same. Again you are dealing with boolean operands. And Dustin is right that this all also depends on the context. In relational database systems we invoke boolean operations on boolean *expressions* (which can be constants, columns, comparisions, function return values or query results).

Comment: I agree with you, @ThorstenKettner, but is there a non-generic version?

Comment: Calling it xor input or xor operand should do the trick. If you are dealing with sets, consider using notation from set theory: `A xor B = A Δ Β = ( A \ B ) U ( B \ A )`

Comment: @Dustin I do not really get your point, can you describe it more?

Comment: Sure @Xanlantos . Consider in what domain you are using XOR. Are you currently talking about XOR-gates in logical circuits / networks, such as Neural Networks or your everyday control circuit? Just call it XOR inputs, everyone will understand. Are you talking about sets of things, and want to describe all elements that belong to either one of the sets, but not both? Consider using set theory notation or describing it as I just did. In domains such as networking with IP addresses or taking XOR of data columns, just name what you xor. "If we XOR the IP Adress with the Subnetmask"...